# Can the NLog {aspnet-session:variable=IntID} renderer extract/display integers from HttpContext.Session[IntID]?

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core-mvc, nlog, asp.net-core-3.1

Before posting elaborate code details, just want to ask if this is possible.  Currently I can render strings extracted from Session, but not INTs (no value, eventhough they have value in Session).
If it's not possible, then this problem's solved.  If it is possible, I can't determine what's wrong, & I'll return to post details.

NUTSHELL EXPLANATION - in a Controller:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("SID", (int)userCreds.ProfileSessionId); //custom session id set as INT
HttpContext.Session.SetString("TID", userCreds.TimezoneId);           //timezone id set as STRING
```

NLOG TARGET:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="T:\test.log"
 layout="[sid: ${aspnet-session:variable=SID}] [tid: ${aspnet-session:variable=TID}]" />
```

NLOG OUTPUT:

```
[sid:    ] [tid: 3]
```

So the string value renders, but the INT value never renders anything.

NLog ref docs mention nothing about extracting INTs from Session, and their example only shows extracting STRINGs from Session.  So, can you render an INT from Session using {aspnet-session}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this is a bug/limitation in the current implementation of `${aspnet-session}` for ASP.NET Core. (Failing unit test could be seen [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/570))

Unfortunately the type is unknown because in the ASP.NET Core session only bytes are saved.

Currently only strings are supported.

PS: For ASP.NET (non-core). Integers does work.

Comment: Thanks!  Are you associated w/the NLog team at all?  This needs to be noted on the NLog ref docs '{aspnet-session} renderers' page asap!   I wasted 2/3's of a day trying to debug this.  Don't know if I should file this as a bug to NLog team, or do they read NLog posts here?

Comment: I'm one of the maintainers ;). Feel free to edit the wiki. That the int32 isn't working was a surprise. I have to say that HttpContext.Session.SetInt32 is a bit funky IMO.

Comment: Ok thank you. Did not have time to read your link originally.  Do agree, wouldn't have expected the Int32 to be saved using a byte array.